# The alternative rule in P1787 for whether a set of non-static member functions can be overloaded

Tags: c++, overloading, language-lawyer, class-members

After reading [P1787](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r5.html), I have a confusion about the comment in this example. That is:

```cpp
struct X {
  static void f();
  void f() const;  // error: redeclaration
  void g();
  void g() const;  // OK
  void g() &;      // error: redeclaration
};
```

Obviously, they're invalid overload declarations if per [over.load](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.load) in the current standard. however, the subclause has been removed in P1787.
According to what says in P1787, I can understand the comment after the second declaration for name `f`, because the first declaration and the second declaration are corresponding and they declared the same entity, however, they violate the following rule:

> For any two declarations of an entity
>
> > If one declares it to be a variable or function, the other shall declare it as one of the same type.

Frankly, I can't understand the comments after the last declaration for the name `g`. IIUC, these three declarations for name `g` do not correspond. Because of the following rule:

> Two declarations correspond if they (re)introduce the same name, both declare constructors, or both declare destructors, unless:
>
> > - [...]
> > - each declares a function or function template, except when
> >
> > > - both declare functions with the same parameter-type-list[Footnote: An implicit object parameter ([over.match.funcs]) is not part of the parameter-type-list. — end footnote], equivalent ([temp.over.link]) trailing requires-clauses (if any, except as specified in [temp.friend]), and, **if both are non-static members, the same cv-qualifiers (if any) and ref-qualifier (if both have one)**

Although they have the same parameter-type-list, they're all non-static members and do not have the same **cv-qualifiers and ref-qualifier**, hence they're not corresponding declarations. I can't find any rule that says such declarations for `g` are ill-formed in P1787, so how to interpret the comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ref-qualifier only needs to be the same *"(if both have one)"*.

If only one declaration has a ref-qualifier and the other doesn't, the wording implies that the two declarations correspond, assuming all other conditions are satisfied.

In the provided example, that means `void g() &;` is a redeclaration of `void g();`.

Comment: Oops, that's my misreading. So, `void g() &;` and `void g();` are corresponding, and they declare the same entity. however, they violate the rule `For any two declarations of an entity, If one declares it to be a variable or function, the other shall declare it as one of the same type.` Right?

Comment: @jackX yes, that is correct. Sorry I was reviewing paragraph 9 of `[basic.link]` to confirm the relationship between the rule you quoted and `[basic.scope.scope]`.

Comment: The relevant rule is:  Two declarations of entities declare the same entity if, considering declarations of unnamed types to introduce their names for linkage purposes, if any ([dcl.typedef], [dcl.enum]), **they correspond** ([basic.scope.scope]), **have the same target scope that is not a function or template parameter scope**, and either: they appear in the same translation unit.  Up to here, that's sufficient to prove they shall be the same entity.

Comment: @jackX yes, that is what I had reviewed before replying...

Comment: So, about `cv-qualifiers`, if one of these declarations has one, then they all should have the same `cv-qualifiers` such that they correspond, otherwise they're not corresponding, Right?

Comment: @jackX the combination of `const` and `volatile` has to be the same for two function declarations in order for them to correspond.

Comment: That's my meaning. It's different with `ref-qualifier` whose requirement is, first, two declarations shall both have `ref-qualifier` and then compare whether they have the same `ref-qualifier`, if they do then they correspond.